# Evaluation inside text cell returns InputForm output

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

I just have discovered that it is possible to incorporate calculation in a text cell (you can create a text cell by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>) by highlighting the formula and typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shilt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but in the following case the output is a ugly `InputForm` result. How can I get a good-looking 2D expression as the output?

[image]

Here is the formula

```
 \!\(
  \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(t\)]\(
  \*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-\ ρ\)\ s\)] \[DifferentialD]s\)\)
```

Comment: With your example, I get a neatly formatted result.  Your result is in `InputForm`.  I don't know why.  You may be able to use the `Cell > Convert To` menu to get a better result.

Comment: Whatever I do I have the same result

Comment: The picture is fine but I recommend to also include the Mathematica code to make life easy on those would help.

Comment: I also get a formated result. However you might try to add `//TraditionalForm` after your integral expression.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch This issue seems only to happen on a code piece inside a text cell. I've tried to edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. It turns out to be necessary to highlight the code after the cursor is moved into the embedded cell. Notice when the cursor is inside the embedded cell, the background is colored:

[image]